# @angular/fire Real Time Database: How to get key and value under it

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire5

### Background

I am using ionic 4 with "@angular/fire": "^5.0.2"

### The Issue

I want to list all the values under profile node, here's my firebase structure:
[image: Brian Firebase]

I want to get the key, location, ownerName, and restoName. I will use the key later on to open another node. And for the code below, I want to display the location, ownerName, and restoName.

### My Code

In **home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { UserProfile } from './../../models/user-profile';
import { RestoProfile } from './../../models/resto-profile';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  restoProfileData: AngularFireList<RestoProfile[]>;
  restoProfileRef: AngularFireList<RestoProfile[]>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    private toast: ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Welcome to brianApp-customer, ${data.email}`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();

        this.restoProfileRef = this.afDatabase.list<RestoProfile>(`profile/`);
        this.restoProfileData = this.restoProfileRef.snapshotChanges();

      }
      else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Could not find authentication details`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In **home.html**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let data of restoProfileData | async">
    <h2>Key: {{ data.payload.key }}</h2>
    <h2>Location: {{data.payload.val().location}}</h2>
    <h2>ownerName: {{data.payload.val().ownerName}}</h2>
    <h2>restoName: {{data.payload.val().restoName}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This code results to `Object(...) is not a function`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can access profile property directly from the `data` object.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let data of restoProfileData | async">
    <h2>Key: {{ data.key }}</h2>
    <h2>Location: {{data.location}}</h2>
    <h2>ownerName: {{data.ownerName}}</h2>
    <h2>restoName: {{data.restoName}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I still get `Runtime Error: Object(...) is not a function`

Comment: Can you please which line of code throwing this error ?

Comment: I suppose it's from the home.html. Because when I comment out the `<ion-list>`, there is no error.

Comment: If you click on the error, it will tell you the exact location of error.

Comment: I cannot click the error. What I can see in my browser, under the `Object(...) is not a function`, is Stack. Then `listChanges/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:84911:28 SwitchMapSubscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:62313:22 Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:13` and the line goes on

Comment: by the way in package.json I have this `"rxjs": "5.5.11"` Do I need to upgrade this to latest one?

Comment: rxjs 5 is no longer supported in AngularFire2 5.0.0-rc.8 or higher, upgrade to 6 and include rxjs-compat

npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I need to update my rxjs and rxjs-compat to version 6.3.3.

```
npm install rxjs@6.3.3 rxjs-compat@6.3.3 --save
```

There's no change in code. Still the same with my question above.